# jquery mobile momentum scrolling on iOS and jqm1.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

As of jqm1.4 it seems like the native like "momentum scrolling" on iOS is no more.

Anyone know how this effect can be achieved? I feel like my app really falls short without it.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two properties to the element

```
#your-scrollable-element {
   overflow: scroll;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

In [Apple's list of supported CSS properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html) they describe the touch behavior as "Native-style scrolling. Specifying this style has the effect of creating a stacking context (like opacity, masks, and transforms)."